# Windows Experience Index score on two CPU not as expected

Tags: windows-7, intel-core-i7, windows-experience-index

I have a Dell XPS 720, from 2008, running an Intel Core 2 Quad Q6600 @2.4Ghz, and a new MacBook Pro running Intel Core i7 M640 @ 2.8Ghz. (The MBP was obviously "boot camped")

I had expected the MBP to outpace the Dell at least on the CPU score, but the WEI for the Dell is 7.1 and for the MBP is 7.0. Is it reasonable that the CPU score hasn't changed over the last 24 months of Quad core improvements by Intel.  Perhaps I'm missing something

Comment: `Perhaps I'm missing something` - WEI is not a tool to check for processor performance

Comment: *Sathya* is correct.  The WEI is not a tool to accurately benchmark a system's performance.  You should look into additional benchmarking utilities to see the true system performance.  I am voting to close this question because of this reasons.

Comment: I'm not trying to accurately benchmark a system's performance.  I'm trying to understand the values that WEI spits out.  I have the nearly the same CPU score for two different machines, when I would have thought there to be a greater disparity.  The question was not a debate of the relative merits of WEI to other benchmarking tools.

Comment: `The question was not a debate of the relative merits of WEI to other benchmarking tools.` - it essentially is. WEI pulls out a number which is useless and has no practical value except for frivolous `my-WEI-is-better-than-yours` debate. If you *really* want to know theoretically how good the new i7 compares to the older Q6600 - you must use other benchmarking tools. Also - comparing a desktop processor to a laptop one is not a direct apples-to-apples comparison @Ralph

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a proper performance test give [PassMark Performance Test 7](http://www.passmark.com/products/pt.htm) a shot, it'll give you much more accurate results.

EDIT: Since you want specific information about why the WEI score is lower for the MBP processor I should point out that the i7 M640 is a dual core CPU with 4 threads whereas the Q6600 is actually quad core. This would mean your MBP CPU is performing considerably better than its Core 2 dual core counterparts of 2 years ago just not when compared to Core 2 quad core counterparts.

Just for a comparison the WEI score for the CPU on my mid 2009 MBP with a Core 2 Duo P7550 @ 2.26GHz gets 5.8

[Core i7 M640 on ark.intel.com](http://ark.intel.com/Product.aspx?id=49666&code=Intel%C2%AE+Core%E2%84%A2+i7-640M+Processor+(4M+Cache,+2.80+GHz))

[Core 2 Quad Q6600 on ark.intel.com](http://ark.intel.com/Product.aspx?id=29765&code=Intel%C2%AE+Core%E2%84%A22+Quad+Processor+Q6600+(8M+Cache,+2.40+GHz,+1066+MHz+FSB))

Comment: no doubt there are a dozens of wonderful performance tests out there.  This question is specifically about WEI.

Comment: See my edit above.

Answer (score 0):

WEI is an aggregate score giving you an overall impression of system speed.

To see why it may be lower on the MBP we would need to see all the individual scores for each component.